# How can I replace an infinite loop in Java with an executor?

Tags: java, infinite-loop, executorservice

Previously I had a thread with an infinite loop, constantly taking elements off a queue:

```
public void start() {
    new Thread(task(), "Publish").start();
}

@SuppressWarnings("InfiniteLoopStatement")
private Runnable task() {
    return () -> {
        while (true) {
            someMethodThatTakesFromAQueue();
        }
    };
}
```

now instead I want to use ExecutorService and the best I've come up with so far is

```
public void start() {
    Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1)
            .scheduleWithFixedDelay(
             this::someMethodThatTakesFromAQueue, 0, 1, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS);
}
```

but I don't like the fact I have to give a non-zero delay between executions when actually I just want it to be executed immediately for ever, since the take on the queue will block till there's a job on the queue to process.

Are there any alternatives?

Comment: you can use producer consumer model. When and to work on data then you can use multithreading

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want ExecutionService in the first place, since you are just blocking in the running task, there are no benefits for reusing threads, just additional overhead for creating and maintaining ExecutionService, this is becomes expensive single Thread.

If you want to use ExecutionService meaningfully, instead of while(true) loop, you could just add new task to ExecutionService, which does unit of work, that you need. Than, to increase performance you could increase ExecutionService thread pool size, so that 2 tasks would run in parallel, or reuse this ExecutionService somewhere else, otherwise stay with Thread implementation, that you wrote.

Comment: Primarily I want to avoid writing while (true) which feels ugly and to shorten my code/make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Threre are other [threadpools available](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html), for example the fixed threadpool (`newFixedThreadPool`), which seems to behave just as the one you use, only without the sceduling.